# kernel: FS-Cache: Duplicate cookie detected - what is this?

Tags: kernel, cache

In Arch Linux, after installing the most recent updates today, I see the following errors in the journal:

```
kernel: FS-Cache: Duplicate cookie detected
kernel: FS-Cache: O-cookie
```

There are about 20 lines in total that are like these. I don't find any info on this via a search. Is this a serious or known problem?

My CPU is an Intel Core i7 with an Asus motherboard. I can provide any requested relevant info. However, at this moment, I don't know what I'm looking at, so I am not sure what info is relevant.

UPDATE: on a 2nd reboot there are fewer of the messages. Here is the complete output of  journalctl -b -p err

```
kernel: FS-Cache: Duplicate cookie detected
kernel: FS-Cache: O-cookie c=000000001e72b895 [p=0000000089da8da7 fl=222 nc=0 na=1]
kernel: FS-Cache: O-cookie d=00000000c3a2cbed n=00000000f757123a
kernel: FS-Cache: O-key=[10] '040002000801c0a805c3'
kernel: FS-Cache: N-cookie c=00000000ea48db1d [p=0000000089da8da7 fl=2 nc=0 na=1]
kernel: FS-Cache: N-cookie d=00000000c3a2cbed n=000000000f72327e
kernel: FS-Cache: N-key=[10] '040002000801c0a805c3'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This appears to be working as intended. The `Duplicate cookie detected` errors are not indicative of a situation that requires action by the sysadmin.

> As has been pointed out on the upstream bug report this may well be working as intended https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=200145#c12
>   https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=ec0328e46d6e5d0f17372eb90ab8e333c2ac7ca9

And:

> fscache: Maintain a catalogue of allocated cookies
>   Maintain a catalogue of allocated cookies so that cookie collisions can be
>   handled properly.  For the moment, this just involves printing a warning
>   and returning a NULL cookie to the caller of fscache_acquire_cookie(), but
>   in future it might make sense to wait for the old cookie to finish being
>   cleaned up.
>
> This requires the cookie key to be stored attached to the cookie so that we
>   still have the key available if the netfs relinquishes the cookie.  This is
>   done by an earlier patch.
>
> The catalogue also renders redundant fscache_netfs_list (used for checking
>   for duplicates), so that can be removed.

Comment: I see this bug when i try to mount samba disk of Microsoft Server 2019. Mounting works perfectly in Win10.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug report open about this topic on ArchLinux bug tracker :
https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/59058

Comment: That's the bug report I filed. However, I learned that bugs.archlinux.org is not the right place for this bug report. People with this issue should  contact upstream using
linux-cachefs@redhat.com (moderated list) or linux-kernel@vger.kernel.org (open list). Also, there is a better bug report here: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=200145